# Unexpected token case switch statements

Tags: switch-statement, token

I don't see what i'm doing wrong

```
var user = prompt ("You are minding you own bissueness when a man in a big white van pulls up? What do you do run, pop a cap in his *error 343*, or hop in?").toLowerCase();
switch (user)
    case 'run':
        var headstart = propmt ("Let's hit it. Did you run track or Cross Country this year? Yes or no?").toLowerCase();
        var fast = prompt ("Are you fast? Yes or No?").toLowerCase();
        if (headstart === 'yes' || fast === 'yes')
        {
            console.log("You live to cruze another day?");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Sorry... you were taken and sold in to Mexico");
        }
        break;
    case 'pop a cap in his *error 343*':
        var gun = prompt(" Ok, we went with gun. Do you have a gun on you? Yes or No").toLowerCase()
        var loaded = prompt("Is you gun loaded? Yes or No?").toLowerCase()
        if (gun === 'yes' && loaded === 'yes')
        {
            console.log("There were no witnesses, you get away clean!");
        }
        break;
    case 'hop in':
        console.log("He turned out to be a nice man and lets you work in Mexico for free forever!")
        break;
        default:
        console.log("I didn't understand your choice.");
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Everything after switch needs to be inside the squiggly brackets. I had the same problem earlier today.

You had:

```
switch(x)
   case 1:
       //statement
       break;
   case 2:
       //statement
       break;
```

What you should have:

```
 switch(x)
    {             //You were missing this bracket
       case 1:
           //statement
           break;
       case 2:
           //statement
           break;
    }             //You were also missing this bracket
```